# How can I store js output in php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to store my javascript output in PHP. I mean, my js code is:

```
function loadCurrentUser () {
var url = APIPATH + 'load_current_user.php' ;
var result = $.ajax({
    type : "GET" ,
    url : url,
    async : false
}). responseText ;
var resultJSON = processJSONResult(result);
}
```

What I want is to store the output I received (in json format) to my variable $json (in php). How can I do that?

Comment: In this case, `result` will be assigned a jQuery object, which is probably not what you're thinking the value is. Is this really what you want?

Comment: By "store" what do you mean? An AJAX call starts with a request and ends with a response. You can't "permanently" store something in a server side variable if you don't use something like a database. If  I've got what you're trying to do, you're probably calling a php script after getting your resultJSON, setting $json = [yourjavascriptresultJSON], but it WON'T store it forever, it will be stored until your PHP script responds with something, after that the value will be lost, unless you store it somewhere else (like in a database).

Comment: @briosheje I am new to jQuery. I suppose that what I was doing is to send GET request to load_current_user.php and retrieve the result by my php script (in json format). If load_current_user.php gives " { "success":1} " then I want to store this to my php variable $json so that i can decode it later using json_decode()

Comment: What do you mean by "later"? keep in mind that PHP is a **server side language** while javascript is a **client side language** (sometimes even a server, but it's not your case). When you use your comfort $.ajax, you're calling a PHP script FROM javascript, asking him something and waiting for a response. Unless you need to use json_decode in order to actually do something immediatly and get an answer or parse some data in a database or somewhere else you can do that, but if you want to call the script and give him a variable this is not the way to do it, because the value will be lost ;)

Comment: @briosheje I know that too.. But for now I just want to store the json response I got from ajax to $json php var :)

Comment: Again, to be clearer: once you call a php script and send something to it, it will only last until the call ends, after that every php variable is lost, because the php script has exited. If you just want to receive it and use it immediatly, just add a data parameter to your ajax request, giving an index and a value (like this: data: {'yourindex':'yourvalue'}) and get it from your php script using $_GET['yourindex'];. A basic tutorial for this can be found here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ (official jQuery documentation), at the bottom of the page ;) http://prntscr.com/53nqr3

Comment: For analogies: If PHP were a math student solving math problems for you (a single page request being a "math problem"), he'd be *throwing away all his work once he finds the answer*, and gives you (the browser) the *only* copy of his answer. Two milliseconds after he has given you his answer, he remembers nothing of it. Some possible ways of storing information would be in a database, in a Cookie, or in some semi-permanent JavaScript/browser storage like "window.localStorage"

Answer (score 0):

based on the comments above it cannot be done as you think. But if you insist on getting response date to a php variable you will have to make another ajax call as ajax call occur at client side and php runs in your server not on the browser @briosheje had explained it nicely. may be what you need is session variable ($_SESSION['index']) to store your response data